# C# Is it possible to use the remove method in reverse?

Tags: c#

I know the remove method is used like this:

```
string MyString = "Hello Beautiful Magic World";
Console.WriteLine(MyString.Remove(5,10));
// The example displays the following output:
// Hello Magic World
```

I want to keep the 5 characters at the end of the string ("World" in our example) constant and remove the previous 5 characters.

But I don't have the slightest idea how to do it. I tried like this: Unfortunately it did not.

```
MyString.Substring(0, MyString.Length - 10 - 5);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me: what do you want the result to be exactly?

Comment: Can you please provide a pattern in which you want your string to be updated

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. One would be to remove World, then remove the string / length you want to remove, and then add World back. Another would be to get the start index where you want to start removing and then also use a count (substring).

Comment: One elegant if slightly cryptic way is to use ranges: `MyString[..^11] + MyString[^5..] == "Hello Beautiful World"`. If you know `^` means "from the end", it's a little more obvious.

Comment: Aside, you say you want to remove the five characters before `World`, but I assume you either mean _six_ characters, _or_ you mean the five characters before ` World`. Otherwise, in this example, you'd end up with "Hello Beautiful MWorld", which I suspect isn't what you want.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1):

The following will find the word "Magic" and remove it:

```cs
string stringToRemove = myString.Remove(myString.Length - 11, 6);
```